# How do I pass a variable number of arrays in a hash to the List::Compare perl module?

Tags: perl, list, hash, compare

I know this question has been asked before here ([compare multiple hashes for common keys merge values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320012/compare-multiple-hashes-for-common-keys-merge-values)). As far as I can tell, it went unanswered.  If you answer, please include an example that uses the List::Compare->new() constructor.

[List::Compare](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Compare) has the ability to accept multiple arrays as input. However, there are no examples that explain how to do so if you do not know in advance how many there will be passed to the constructor.

Example from the man page:

```
$lcm = List::Compare->new(\@Al, \@Bob, \@Carmen, \@Don, \@Ed);
```

or...

You may use the 'single hashref' constructor format to build a
List::Compare object to process three or more lists at once:

`$lcm = List::Compare->new( { lists => [\@Al, \@Bob, \@Carmen, \@Don, @Ed], } );`

or

```
$lcm = List::Compare->new( { 
        lists => [\@Al, \@Bob, \@Carmen, \@Don, \@Ed],
        unsorted => 1, } );
```

I need to use this 'single hashref' constructor above, because I don't know how many lists (arrays) will be passed to the constructor. The closest I come is this:

```
my %l;
my @a = ("fred", "barney", "pebbles", "bambam", "dino");
my @b = ("george", "jane", "elroy", "judy");
my @c = ("homer", "bart", "marge", "maggie");
my @d = ("fred", "barney", "pebbles", "bambam", "dino");
my @e = ("fred", "george", "jane", "elroy", "judy", "pebbles");

$l{'lists'}{'a'} = [ @a ];
$l{'lists'}{'b'} = [ @b ];
$l{'lists'}{'c'} = [ @c ];
$l{'lists'}{'d'} = [ @d ];
$l{'lists'}{'e'} = [ @e ];

my $lc = List::Compare->new(\%l);
my @intersection = $lc->get_intersection;
print @intersection . "\n";
```

I am getting:

Need to define 'lists' key properly:  at /usr/local/share/perl5/List/Compare.pm line 21.

The Compare.pm code (line 21) is:

```
die "Need to define 'lists' key properly: $!"
        unless ( ${$argref}{'lists'}
             and (ref(${$argref}{'lists'}) eq 'ARRAY') );
```

Can someone tell me how to construct and name this hash from simple arrays?  I need to be able to process a wide and varied number of them continuously. There could possibly be hundreds of arrays involved.

---

**Update**

@Borodin's answer was exactly what I needed. I apologize for the bad data, was trying to come up with something concise.  Here is what derived from that code

```
my @sets_to_process = qw( DOW SP500 has_trend_lines_day );
my @sets;
my $num_sets = $#sets_to_process;

for my $i (0 .. $num_sets) {
    my @set = get_ids_in_list( $dbh, $sets_to_process[$i] );
    push @sets, \@set;
}

my $lc = List::Compare->new(@sets);
my @intersection = $lc->get_intersection;

print "Sets:\n";
printf "  %s\n", join ', ', @$_ for @sets;
print "\n";

print "Intersection:\n";
printf "  %s\n", @intersection? join(', ', @intersection) : 'None';
print "\n";
```

Comment: You may not know how many lists there are when you write the program, but the program knows how many there are at the point of the call, right?

Comment: I'm glad your problem is fixed, but you shouldn't post another solution in order to say so. You don't have to say anything, but if you do then it should be as a comment on the answer that helped. Ultimately you can upvote (or downvote) solutions that you think are good (or useless) for whatever reason. And if your problem has been resolved then you should *accept* the solution that works best for you, by clicking the green tick mark, so that others can see that the question needs no further input. Welcome to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your parameter construction is that you are defining `%l` (a dreadful identifier, by the way) as a hash containing a hash of arrays, like this

```
(
  lists => {
    a => ["fred", "barney", "pebbles", "bambam", "dino"],
    b => ["george", "jane", "elroy", "judy"],
    c => ["homer", "bart", "marge", "maggie"],
    d => ["fred", "barney", "pebbles", "bambam", "dino"],
    e => ["fred", "george", "jane", "elroy", "judy", "pebbles"],
  },
)
```

but the documentation is clear that it should be a simple hash containing an array of arrays

```
(
  lists => [
    ["fred", "barney", "pebbles", "bambam", "dino"],
    ["george", "jane", "elroy", "judy"],
    ["homer", "bart", "marge", "maggie"],
    ["fred", "barney", "pebbles", "bambam", "dino"],
    ["fred", "george", "jane", "elroy", "judy", "pebbles"],
  ],
)
```

Furthermore, it doesn't help your problem that *“[You] don't know how many lists (arrays) will be passed to the constructor”* because all that you are doing is pushing the problem inside a data structure instead of keeping it at the parameter level

It is difficult to help you with the data you have given because the intersection is the empty set, so here's a sample program you can experiment with that generates between five and ten sets of sixteen random alphabet letters. It creates different data to work with each time it is run, and passes the list of array references directly as parameters to the `new` constructor instead of using a reference to a hash with a single `lists` element

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util 'shuffle';
use List::Compare;

my @sets;

my $num_sets = 5 + rand(6);

for (1 .. $num_sets) {
  my @set = (shuffle 'A' .. 'Z')[0..16];
  push @sets, [ sort @set ];
}

my $lc = List::Compare->new(@sets);
my @overlap = $lc->get_intersection;

print "Sets:\n";
printf "  %s\n", join ', ', @$_ for @sets;
print "\n";

print "Intersection:\n";
printf "  %s\n", @overlap ? join(', ', @overlap) : 'None';
print "\n";
```

**sample outputs**

```
Sets:
  B, C, D, E, F, G, K, L, M, O, P, Q, S, U, V, W, X
  B, C, D, F, G, I, J, L, M, P, R, T, U, V, W, X, Y
  A, B, C, D, F, G, H, K, L, M, O, R, T, U, V, W, Y
  A, B, D, G, H, I, K, L, M, O, R, T, U, V, W, Y, Z
  A, B, C, D, E, F, H, J, K, L, M, P, Q, S, U, V, Z

Intersection:
  B, D, L, M, U, V
```

```
Sets:
  A, B, C, D, F, J, K, L, M, N, Q, R, U, V, W, X, Y
  A, E, F, G, H, I, J, L, O, P, Q, R, S, T, V, X, Z
  B, E, G, H, J, K, L, M, N, P, S, T, U, V, W, Y, Z
  B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, N, O, Q, R, T, V, W, Z
  A, B, C, E, F, G, H, I, L, N, O, Q, T, U, W, X, Y

Intersection:
  None
```

---

**Update**

With regard to the updated code in your question, your identifier `$num_sets` is wrongly-named as it is the *index* of the final element in `@sets`, or one less than the actual number of sets

If you want to use a variable then you should say

```
my $num_sets = @sets_to_process;
```

and then loop like this

```
for my $i ( 0 .. $num_sets-1 ) { ... }
```

But in this case you don't need the indices at all, and it's probably best to forget about `$num_sets` and write just this

```
for my $set ( @sets_to_process ) {
    my @set = get_ids_in_list($dbh, $set);
    push @sets, \@set;
}
```

or even just use `map` like this

```
my @sets = map [ get_ids_in_list($dbh, $_) ], @sets_to_process;
```